# String validation based on criteria

Tags: java, string, validation, string-formatting, string-comparison

I have a requirement where I need to validate a string:

```
   String input1 = example@gmail.com , example1@gmail.com; 
   String input2 = example@yahoo.com , example1@gmail.com;

        String input 1 == valid ::: Valid because all email ids are of same domain

       String input 2 == invalid
```

Comment: if a string contains all the email id of same domain its true else false

Comment: equals() ?? I dont want to compare . i want to validate individual string

Comment: You'd split the string (first by comma, then split those parts by `@`). Get rid of/ignore any parts you don't need, compare the parts containing the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the logic in the following way. 
String input1 = example@gmail.com , example1@gmail.com , example1@gmail.com;

Follow the steps.

1. Split the entire string using comma (,). You will get an array of email ids.
2. From the above array of email id, separate out the domain by stripping from @ symbol and put in a HashSet. It means the HashSet should contain all the domains.
3. If the HashSet size is 1 finally or at the end it means that input1 has same doamins, as per your requirement it is valid.
4. If the HashSet contains more than 1, as per your requirement it is invalid.

This is a simple logic, However there may be better logic to solve it.

Comment: I am able to split first time how to split second time??

Comment: You can do like this String s = "example1@gmail.com";
    String s1 = s.substring(s.indexOf("@")+1,s.length());